# Refreshing canvas in Python3 / tkinter similar to MATLABs "hold on"

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to create a program which plots an arbitrary number of dots on a canvas based on two sliders (a minimum and a maximum value) where the values are read from a list of data.

The problem I'm having is in refreshing the canvas with new dots each time the sliders are manipulated. The only way I've gotten it to work is to redraw the entire canvas each time the sliders are pulled (as seen in the code snippet below), but this seems rather ineffective and it also produces an annoying flickering. I want the canvas to be sort of static, and then just plot the dots from the list when the sliders are manipulated.

Some sample code that works, although I have abbreviated parts for readability:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg

from tkinter import *
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import tkinter as Tk

list1=[0,1000,3000,5000,10000] #these lists are read from a file, but
list2=[25,50,75,100,120] #I've shortened that part down to make it compact

def slide(*args):
  slidervalue1=var.get()
  slidervalue2=var2.get()
  f = Figure(figsize=(10,8), dpi=75)
  a = f.add_subplot(111)
  a.plot(list1[slidervalue1:slidervalue2],list2[slidervalue1:slidervalue2],'.', color='k')
  canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=root)
  canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=1,column=0, sticky='nw')

root = Tk.Tk()

var=IntVar()
var2=IntVar()

f = Figure(figsize=(10,8), dpi=75)
a = f.add_subplot(111)

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=root)
canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=1,column=0, sticky='w')

toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas,root)
toolbar.update()
toolbar.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='w')

slider=Scale(master=root,from_=1,to=len(perctp),variable=var,orient='horizontal', command=slide)
slider2=Scale(master=root,from_=1,to=len(perctp),variable=var2,orient='horizontal')
slider.grid(row='3', column='0', sticky='w')
slider2.grid(row='3', column='0',sticky='w',padx='150')

Tk.mainloop()
```

I have searched around for the topic and I repeatedly come across "update_idletasks()" but I have not gotten it to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: You want to use blitting.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would be grateful if you could elaborate a bit.

Comment: Sorry, I googled a bit and it seems that I should delve a bit deeper into matplotlib.animation. I will try that and come back if I manage to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve it by using

```
 matplotlib.animation
```

Defining the thing that I want to animate as an empty dot:

```
 dot=plot([],[])
```

And then get the value from the sliders, determining the coordinates of the dot and passing it back from a function

```
 def animate(i):
      calculate stuff
      return dot
```

It took me a while to realize that you need to have the argument "i" in animate, not sure why though.